# Book or website about book design

Tags: book-design

I am planning to study about book design. The final object is that given a book I can write a latex book template to achieve the same style. Could you recommend me some books or website to learn this kind of knowledge? What I have learned is through the book "LaTeX beginner's guide".

Comment: Wow the book design is a very exciting topic. I can think about many books and suggestions to make, but I don't know how much you know about this. Also I do not know what is your language, or what is the book culture in your country. That's important because many decisions about design books depend to some extent on the local or national publishing tradition. I know about few sites and books in Spanish, but surelly you need something in English or another language. Tell us a little bit more please.

Comment: +Aradnix What I want to learn is English book design. I want to translate some English book for free. LaTex is fancy and attracts me deeply. I know some basic LaTeX knowledge and used it for some course assignments and project reports. But I have no experience about book template writing and I want to learn it very very much. So I want some books or website that focus on this topic, not books about every thing of latex or fundamentals.

Comment: @Aradnix wrongly use '+'.. like the google+

Comment: Well, I learned from reading all the books I found about editorial design at my university library. It was something eclectic and believe me that almost none had anything to do with LaTeX. One thing is knowing how to use LaTeX and other design books.

Comment: @Aradnix So your meaning is that learn book design from libbrary and then learn how to implement it from LaTeX books. That is a kind of method. But it is better to have a book covers both of them.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Page_Layout&stable=1 This shows a page layout of a page. Does this contains all elements of a page? And What I need to do is design those elements? That is one of my questions. I saw some book templates code that very complicate. I hope to implement  a book style in a component by component style, like module programming.

Comment: You need to understand what is a book, the anatomy of the book, and a little bit about typography. Well these books can be a good start point for you: Modern Book Design by Ruari McLean. Adrian Frutiger (one of my favourite typographers) has many interesting books about, but I can't find translations in English. [Type and Typography](http://www.amazon.com/Type-Typography-Phil-Baines/dp/0823055280/ref=la_B001H6V0QY_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388037102&sr=1-2) by Phil Baines and Andrew Haslam also can be useful for you.

Comment: This one [Designing with Type](http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Type-5th-Essential-Typography/dp/0823014134/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388037676&sr=1-1&keywords=designing+with+type) by James Craig it's basic, good and very enjoyable. Another one [Thinking with Type](http://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Type-2nd-revised-expanded/dp/1568989695/ref=la_B001JRZFK8_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388037447&sr=1-1) by Ellen Lupton.

Comment: You need to understand about the paper, the page structure and more. For that, my suggestions are these books: [Grid Systems: Principles of Organizing Type](http://www.amazon.com/Grid-Systems-Principles-Organizing-Design/dp/1568984650/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388037881&sr=1-3&keywords=kimberly+elam) by Kimberly Elam. [aking and Breaking the Grid](http://www.amazon.com/Making-Breaking-Grid-Graphic-Workshop/dp/1592531253/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388037978&sr=1-3&keywords=timothy+samara) by Timothy Samara.

Comment: @Aradnix Thanks very much! I will go through these books. Book design is really exciting！I am also looking forward to some reference about LaTeX book design.

Comment: There is a lot of other books I can find useful, but try to start with those and learn also about books. Then you can understand the reasons and how to use a lot of commands in TeX for the layout. Therefore you'll be able to create your own clasees and books.

Comment: Uhm... about LaTeX book design you have to read books about TeX. The documentation of the `KOMA Script` bundle, `sufitesi`, `Tufte` or `Memoir` can be useful also. But I almost forgot one of the most cited books about desing: [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Typographic-Style-Version-Anniversary/dp/0881792128/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1388038373&sr=1-1&keywords=bringhurst+the+elements+of+typographic+style) by Robert Bringhurs. It was an after and before for me about design books.

Comment: @Aradnix +1 for list of books, but especially for Frutiger.

Comment: @Aradnix Seems I will start reading books in the library!

Comment: No body read books any more (ok, some do). People read the web. Learn how to do publication targeting the web. That is the future of publication. Not paper.

Comment: @Nasser But ebook is very convenient and beautiful book design also makes reading more enjoyable. So book design is still very valuable, I believe.

Comment: I was not talking about eBooks. I am talking about direct digital publication to the web itself. This is the future. HTML5 and CSS3 already have very advanced tools to make very well structured layouts on the web. Advanced grid layout, typesetting and more. This is the future of publication. See newspapers moving to the web, etc.. The web allows live content as well, mixed with static content, which makes it much more rich for learning than just paper. If I have the time, that is what I would learn.

Comment: I can't believe @Nasser about the people doesn't read (paper) books anymore. ebooks exists but the technology has not yet a complete replace for the books. There is not an standard yet. Many ebooks (such epub) make awful things with maths. It seems that the ebook designers only thought about novels and literature and forgot to include other kind of books in its specifications. We have no also a comfortable and gently device for our eyes. The tablet and PC screen are not the best for read long texts. Yes, there is kindle and nook but not everyone has one of them.

Comment: @Nasser HTML5 and CSS3 has very nice features, but not enough (for me). The typography in the web is awful the most of times, and it is extremely arid and poor, especially if you are not using google web fonts on your website. If the future is HTML5 and CSS3 what are we doing here learning and using LaTeX and friends?

Comment: I am not going to argue here that the future of publication is the web and not the paper since almost everyone here would disagree with this, being this is a Tex group and no one wants to hear this. But you do whatever you want and learn whatever you want. good luck. Just remember what happened to the encyclopedia britannica and how wikipedia killed it off. `After 244 years, the Encyclopaedia Britannica is going out of print.` http://mediadecoder.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/03/13/after-244-years-encyclopaedia-britannica-stops-the-presses/?_r=0

Comment: Neither HTML5 or CSS3 were designed for be teh future of the publications. In fact, the most of times you get an awful and typographical poor works, if we are talking about books. I never said that the paper books will remain forever. Simply that now we have not a stantard enough flexible for create any kind of ebook. Surelly in a couple of years or decades we'll have, but we must to work about for create it. And I think TeX can help to do this sooner.

Comment: @Nasser: I actually agree with you that the future is in the web, but we're not there yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I thinks is time to answer this question properly instead of create a large chain of comments. In fact I'll recycle few of them here.

First of all, TeX (and LaTeX in some way) is the *translation* of the lead technology used since the mythical Gutenberg to the *digital age*. So, TeX has a lot, hundreds of commands that let you control with great precision where the printer should put the ink and with which form.

Unfortunately although TeX gives great power and control over the page, does not teach you how to design and use all that power correctly and wisely. There is the need to learn some graphic design and typography focused on book design, which is what interests you learn. If you are not pursuing a professional career in design, then you have to learn on your own (like me) what is perhaps somewhat unorthodox.

As I said before, the book design is a very exciting topic. But you should take care about two things *the language*, and *the book culture* in your country. That's important because many decisions about design in books depend to some extent on the local or national publishing tradition.

I can suggest a whole library of books on design and typography books, however I'll try to focus on what may be helpful as a beginner.

### Basic Books

These give you a general introduction, without being exhaustive give you an overview to help you understand what all this.

1. Modern Book Design by Ruari McLean. Is not my favourite, it was a little bit boring for me (was not my first), but is good.
2. Adrian Frutiger is one of the most important typographers of the 20th century (and one of my favourites). He has many interesting books about typography, the most of then I read are published in Spanish by Gustavo Gili Publisher, in English the only one I've found is [Signs and Symbols: Their Design and Meaning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823048268) by Adrian Frutiger.
3. [Type and Typography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823055280) by Phil Baines and Andrew Haslam also can be useful for you. It brings you an enjoyable overview.
4. Once you have a better idea about what is behind the desing of a book, you can learn a little bit more with this one: [Designing with Type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823014134) by James Craig it's basic, good and very enjoyable too.
5. The typographic world can be fascinating but when you are newbie is not easy to think with types. Then [Thinking with Type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568989695) by Ellen Lupton would be perhaps the best choice.

---

### Specialized Books

Now that you know of typefaces, font families, compositions, and so it's time to learn how to use all that. As your aim is design books, you'll need to learn how to create visual structures and use grids.

1. A good start point for this would be [Grid Systems: Principles of Organizing Type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568984650) by Kimberly Elam.
2. [Making and Breaking the Grid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592531253) by Timothy Samara. He has also another nice book for design that you should read later: [Design Elements: A Graphic Style Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592532616).
3. I can't close this section without suggests the books of Edward Tufte, perhaps the most famous: [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961392142).

---

### Books about books

Finally the last suggestions:

1. This one was a before and after for me about the design of a book and also one of the most cited books about desing: [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792128) by Robert Bringhurs.
2. A more *technical* book about the design of books [Book Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0810992205) by the same Andrew Haslam, a famous designer which makes paper engineering for his books.
3. [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226104206), perhaps is not a book for learn to desing a book, but is very useful for write books and has a lot of suggestions you can use for improve your designs, specially in English language.

---

Well, surely there are hundreds or maybe thousands of other books that fall outside this brief list. It was not my intention to make an exhaustive list of course, but to make very specific suggestions on my experience might be of use.

About the websites, I'm afraid that I know of none that can help you, and the only one I could recommend you for visit is in Spanish.

Finally I hope these tips are useful for anyone who wants to delve into the design behind LaTeX classes and understand the reasons behind are based certain decisions and design conventions inherent to all of them.

Comment: Wow! @Aradnix That is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Book Typography: A Designer's Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0948021667). You may find that some of its advice is not easily translatable to TeX; I imagine TeX would be a good tool to get 95% of the job done, but the final touches probably require a professional hand.